# Modifying VO bind variables

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

So, I am trying to modify some VO bind variables inside my application. Currently, I am using executeQueryForCollection() to intercept and modify my variables. Also, I could do the same thing by using VariableValueManager().

I found an article on this website http://www.awasthiashish.com/2015/01/setting-view-object-bind-variable-override-bindparametersforcollection-preparerowsetforquery-executequeryforcollection.html that provides a brief explanation, but it does not say anything about using VariableValueManager().

I was wondering does anyone know what is the best way to intercept and modify bind variables before the query is executed? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the View Object bind variables ? Or Jsf Binding variable?

Comment: View Object bind variables

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically in your controller before sending the request to your model using the VariableValueManager, as you mentionned, is the right way to go.

You can use an utilitary function like the following :

```
public static void setBindVariableValueToViewObjectBindVariable(ViewObject vo, String bindVarName, Object bindVarValue) {
    if (vo != null && bindVarName != null && bindVarValue != null) {
        VariableValueManager vm = vo.ensureVariableManager();
        vm.setVariableValue(bindVarName, bindVarValue);
    }
}
```